# Is there any way to format input timeframe with custom options?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

This - `input.timeframe("")` shows list as *'1 minute', '2 hours', '1 day'* etc. - Yet still returns the numeric/string representation - i.e. 4hr = 240, 1 day = D

I'm aiming to achieve the same but with fewer/custom timeframes *(list)*. But, if I set the `options` parameter (eg. `["6 hours"]`), it returns the string as is - not 360 *(which is required for `security` calls)*

Is there any workaround for this, to show eg. "6 hours" on the list but get the value 360?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return from [input.timeframe()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_input%7Bdot%7Dtimeframe) is not a numeric represenation.
It is always a string.
It will **appear** to be a number if you go into the lower timeframes, though.
Example: the 1 hour timeframe is represented as 60 minutes, so [input.timeframe()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_input%7Bdot%7Dtimeframe) will return the string `60`.
This `60` string can be used in [request.security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity) calls.

**Edit 1** in response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72955967/is-there-any-way-to-format-input-timeframe-with-custom-options/72956081?noredirect=1#comment128860386_72956081) comment:
You can't get `60` directly from the string `1 hour`.
You'll have to translate manually, after you've gotten the input.
Like this.

```
//@version=5
indicator("SO", overlay=false)

i_res = input.timeframe('D', "Resolution", options=['1 hour','D', 'W', 'M'])

res = switch i_res
    '1 hour' => '60'
    => i_res

if barstate.islast
    var label lbl = label.new(na, na, "")
    label.set_xy(lbl, bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(lbl, res)

plot(na)
```

Comment: Yes, BUT how I get the list to show '1 hour' and get value 60? Sorry if the question was confusing. Updated.

Comment: Added Edit 1 to my answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly as I wanted. Thanks!